# End of all actions of actors of particular group

Tags: libgdx

I have board end cells on it. Board is `Group` and cells are `Actor`s, added to board. In one moment I add `MoveToAction`s and custom `RunnableAction`s (one ore more, using `AfterAction`) to cells. After this actions are done, I want to do something else (add new cells, rotate board etc.). I need to know, when all actions are done. Other words, when there are no actions, added to cells.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is CountdownEventAction.

http://javadocmd.com/blog/libgdx-shiny-new-actions/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this.

```
Actor.getActions().size
```

example:

```
if(Actor.getActions().size == 0){


}
```

NEW:

that's how I know, what you can try is to call getChildren group (), and to know in advance which is the actor in each group running in last place or lasts more time to complete if parallel and check only the actor in each cell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a lot of cells. So with this approach I need to check actions for every cell in loop. And for catching the moment when there are no actions, I need one more thread. I think, this can affect performance.